# Update a feature's coordinates/geometry

Tags: openlayers, modify-interaction

Can anyone possibly give me an example of how the Openlayers 3 'setGeometry' method can be used on an ol.Point feature please? I have a feature which has been created from data retrieved from a database and this effectively shows waypoints along a linestring route. When the route is modified I'm using the 'modifyend' event to fire a function which will update the underlying data. The last thing I need to do is find the corresponding marker within an ol.Collection and update it's coordinate property. Looking at the API, it would seem that I should be able to do this with:

```
// results is an array with the old coordinate and the new one
var originalCoordinate = results[0];
var modifiedCoordinate = results[1];

var sourceFeatures = session.markerLayer.getSource().getFeatures();

    sourceFeatures.forEach(displayFeature);

function displayFeature(item, index) {
    var featureGuid = item.get('Guid');
    console.info(featureGuid, index);

    //markerFC.push(marker);
    if (featureGuid == pointGuid) {
        var coords = item.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        item.Longitude = nc4326[0];
        item.Latitude = nc4326[1];
        item.setGeometry(modifiedCoordinate);
        console.info(item, coords, index);
    }
}

item.setGeometry(modifiedCoordinate);
```

But it hasn't changing anything and I get an error in the console saying 'Uncaught Error: addEventListener and attachEvent are unavailable.'

I really don't understand why this is so complicated to do and the only other thing I can think of to do is destroy the feature and create a new one in it's place but that seems a little extreme when I'm only trying to update it's lat/lon properties.

Can anyone please advise how I can handle this?

So, to update this question, the item's geometry does seem to be updating when I set it here but the layer won't refresh and the item appears in it's original position. I've also tried the solution [in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153079/openlayers3-redraw-map-refresh) but it's not working.

Comment: Could do with some more of your code to know why its not working for. There are examples of the use of `setGeometry` in the openlayers docs http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/examples/geolocation.html

Comment: Sorry @user5219763 I realised that as I'd posted the question. I've incorporated the example functionality into my geolocation tracking but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 8):

So apparently setGeometry does not work in the way which I expected. Rather than using:

```
item.setGeometry(modifiedCoordinate);
```

It is necessary to use:

```
item.getGeometry().setCoordinates(modifiedCoordinate);
```

This seems slightly counter-intuitive to me but it soles the problem at least. One issue that this has also raised is finding a reliable method for refreshing a layer's content but I guess that will be another question!