# Map put on hidden tab not shown after tab comes to front in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

I use OpenLayers4 with bootstrap-native.
My page has bootstrap tablist, and I put map layers on a tab which is initially hidden.
But after the tab is selected and comes to front, the map is white-out and is not shown..

How can I make it visible?

I tried

```
mapObject.renderSync();
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153079/openlayers3-redraw-map-refresh) map refresh but it throws error "TypeError: source.getParams is not a function".

I found a workaround by resizing the page, then map is shown.
But I want to display the map without having to resize the page.

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need `map.updateSize`
If you set size of map target element(div) in style(css), simply call `map.updateSize`.
sample codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEOaox)

Comment: +1up-vote it's really help to me (y)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to use the timeout to wait for the div to be displayed.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    map.updateSize();
}, 100);
```